# Updating Nodejs on mac

Tags: node.js, macos, installation, updating

I am using macOS Big Sur and want to update my Node. However, after downloading its file from the official website and completing its installation, my terminal still shows and uses my previous node version.

Does anyone know how can I overcome this issue?

Thanks

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIkhE.png)

Comment: Make sure you uninstall node before installing the new version. Also, make sure you restart your terminal after installing node. Additionally, you make want to look into using Node Version Manager (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#intro) if you're switching Node versions often.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suggest using nvm. It's much simpler and eradicates the headache of updating.

### nvm

To do this, you can install nvm. https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating

you will be pasting in the curl command `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`

Note: when this is finished running, you should see a line near the bottom which says something like `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"`

Copy and paste this and hit enter.

Then check to make sure you have nvm installed now `nvm -v`

### Nodejs update

After, in the terminal, type: `nvm install node` (you can also check your current version first with `node -v`

Run it and then check node version again. It should be updated.

### npm

While you're at it, you can also update npm.

Check version `npm -v`
Update `npm install -g npm`

This should do it. Let me know if there are any issues. Note: this can all be done in the -zsh shell, no reason to move back to bash.

Comment: thank you. this is the best method, succinct and headache free.

Comment: I did this, but after quitting the terminal, and opening it again, `node --version` displays another version.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) on your Mac, it is simple as that:

```
brew install node
```

If you already have a node version installed, you can upgrade it like this:

```
brew upgrade node
```

Then force to link the brew node version:

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

These examples install the latest node version. If you prefer a specific version add the version number like `node@21` when installing or upgrading.